# Computing covariance matrix of two mode state?

Tags: quantum-optics

Suppose that I want to calculate the covariance matrix of the state of modes $A$ and $C$ with quadrature $(x_a, p_a)$ and $(x_b,p_b)$ . But instead of the state in order to calculate all expectation values, I have the covariance matrix correspond to it. How can I compute all expectation values by using covariance matrix? In fact how can I find the covariance matrix of the state of modes $A$ and $C$?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have the CM or do you want to calculate it?

Comment: I want to calculate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The covariance matrix is a kind of a description of a quantum state that is an alternative to a density matrix or a wavefunction. So *calculation* of it implies that you know a particular state you are dealing with in other representation (density matrix, wavefunction, Q/W/P-function) then you can calculate all the expectations. For example for a coherent state you know the wavefunction in the Fock basis:
$\vert \alpha \rangle = 1/a \sum_{n} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\vert n \rangle$ ($a$ is for normalization). From this you can calculate all the expectations in the definition of the CM (it pretty easy, especially if you replace the quadrature operators with combinations of ladder ones). Alternatively you can just *define* a state with a CM: you can write/measure a matrix, check whether it is a valid CM, and if it is - here is your state.